# Unable to push local database to heroku using pg:push

Tags: postgresql, heroku, flask

I am working on a Flask project, and I am ready to deploy my database to Heroku, but I am getting the following error when I try to push my local database to my PG database. I have searched through other StackOverflow posts, but no proposed solutions seem to work. Here is the error message:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "database-name" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    `Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting`
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       psql failed. exit status 512, output: "" (RuntimeError)
    Command:     heroku pg:push database-name DATABASE_URL --app app-name
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.39.5 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
    Error ID:    020bc5cc53ec48298f24125be8705f53
```

Any insight would be much appreciated. I have been struggling with this for several hours. Thanks!

Comment: how are you 'push my local database to my PG database'? I use sqlalchemy and alembic. And with this I need to run alembic migrations on my production server when the models change. Are you using SQLALchemy?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQLAlchemy and alembic. For some reason, I am unable to get migrations to work (I have flask-migrate), so as a short-term solution, I created a new Heroku app with an empty PG database and would like to push my local database to it. Reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push

Comment: does a backup / restore work. You can do this using the pgadmin III tool

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no existing remote database that will work. I have (1) a remote database that needs migrations applied to it and (2) an empty remote database.